# How to split string from localstorage into array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have stored a list of image paths as string in localstorage with the key 'interest', i am attempting to access this list in localstorage and split the list into an array. However, when using the explode function the string does not split but is stored into the array as one item.
Any advice on how to fix this.
I have attached my code currently:
This is the output of the PHP code: Array ( [0] => ./Images/2.png/ ./Images/3.png/ ./Images/4.png/ )

```js
<script> // stores array in localstorage joined with a space
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selectedi = selected.join(" ");
                    localStorage.setItem('interests', JSON.stringify(selectedi));
                }
</script>

//in order to retrieve list in php
<?php
$interests = "<script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests')));</script>";
$arrayinterests = explode(" ",$interests);
print_r($arrayinterests);

?>
```

Comment: $interests contains the script code, it doesn't contain the value of the localStorage "interests". Since you need JS to access the localStorage (client side) consider using Ajax - so you'll get the interests value from the localStorage and send it to PHP (server side) for further manipulations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can not read values directly from browser's localStorage.
Also your code generates this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests')));</script>
)
```

You simply store JS-code in a PHP string variable and then explode **the code**, not the value of `interests`.

If you want to pass data from browser to PHP then you must perform a HTTP request (GET or POST or something else) and pass the data as parameters. However that would be too long to explain here.

Comment: I think the script part is getting executed after the exploding is being done, which is leading to faulty results. A workaround would be to explode the now-generated string in `$arrayinterests[0]`  again, as depicted in my answer below. That's not the best of solutions but can work to get the job done.

Comment: no, it wont work at all. PHP code is executed on the server before being sent to the browser, JS code is executed in browser. The fun fact is `$arrayinterests[0]` will contain EXACTLY the same text as `$interests` :)

Comment: But the OP has indicated that his $arrayinterests does contain the string of filenames. My answer is based upon that assumption.

Comment: @AkashDas well then he should change his example code because it doesn't match to what he says.